# Can't create [id] attribute in Grakn

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I'm trying to define a new attribute `id` like so:

```
define 
id sub attribute, datatype double;
```

However when I try this, I get this syntax error:

```
define id sub attribute, datatype double;
       ^
no viable alternative at input 'id'
syntax error at line 1: 
define id sub attribute, datatype double;
       ^
mismatched input 'id' expecting {'match', 'define', 'undefine', 'insert', 'compute'}
All uncommitted data is cleared
```

Is it not possible to create an attribute called `id`?

Answer (score 0):

`id` is a reserved keyword in Graql.

Therefore, you cannot have a user-defined type called `id`, I suggest using `identifier` instead.

`id` is used for matching concepts in Grakn by their Grakn-generated id, like so:

```
match $x id V12345; get;
```

although the recommended approach is instead to match using a user-defined `key`.